# using login controls with sql server (not express)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, forms-authentication, login-control, sqlmembershipprovider

I installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional(updated with SP1), then I uninstalled SQL server 2005 Express and installed SQL Server 2005 Standard.

now I am not able to add 'SQL Server Database' to the project - it says 
    Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly.

Is it not compliant with SQL Server Standard version?

And Login Controls also not working-
Web Administration Tool says 
    Unable to connect to SQL Server database

Also tried with aspnet_regsql command-line utility.. not working..(actually I dont know what is to be done after creating SQL server database through 'aspnet_regsql command-line utility')

Please Provide a solution for my problem before somebody Closes this question or marks for deletion  ;P :)

Comment: There is no reason for anyone to close this question, or to mark for deletion, except for your smart remark about closing questions. Reading the [faq] would be a lot smarter.

Comment: You may have to reinstall Visual Studio. A "Repair" install may be enough. You installed it while SQL Server Express was on the system; now it's not. You have lied to it, now apologize and tell the truth.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: that 'smart remark about closing questions' was just for fun.. I felt some people may find it too basic question, but I am having serious problem.. :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders: If I have lied to VS, then there should be some way to reveal the truth without killing and recreating it.. You have any Idea about that? :)

Comment: Yes. A "Repair" install. And questions don't get closed for being too basic, and this isn't a basic question in any case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Error while repair: Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard failed to install..and no difference in problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality to just *attach* a stand-alone `.mdf` file as a database is indeed available in the **Express** editions of SQL Server **only**.

What you should do in any other case is create the database on the SQL Server instance, and refer to it by its **database name** - not it's .mdf file name.

In order to create those tables and stored procedures needed for the ASP.NET membership and role subsystem, you need to use the `aspnet_regsql` utility against your SQL Server instance. You said that didn't work - **how** does it not work?? Did you get an error ?? If so: **what error**??

See the [MSDN docs on aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for details on how to use it. To create the ASP.NET membership and role subsystem, use:

```
aspnet_regsql -S (your server name here) -E -A mr
```

The `-E` uses integrated security (e.g. your current Windows logon) to connect to SQL Server - that user accounts needs enough permissions for these operations, of course! If you need a specific SQL Server user, there's are the two `-U (username) -P (password)` parameters to achieve this.

Once you have all of this, you also need to configure your ASP.NET membership and role subsystem to actually **use** that new database (`ASPNETDB`) that was created on your SQL Server. By default, they use the `aspnetdb.mdf` file attached to your SQL Server Express instance. Since you've changed that, you need to update your configuration! See [how to do this in detail on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx)

**Step 1:** add a connection string to your newly created database

In your `web.config` or `app.config`, add a valid connection string to your newly created ASP.NET membership/role database - something like:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ASPNETDB_Connection" 
           connectionString="Server=YourServer;database=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Step 2:** - add a valid configuration for the ASP.NET membership subsystem and reference that new connection string you've just added in Step 1; something like:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <membership defaultProvider="YourProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
          <providers>
             <clear />
             <add name="YourProvider" 
                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                  connectionStringName="ASPNETDB_Connection"
                  applicationName="MyApplication"
                  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
                  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                  passwordFormat="Hashed" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
```

**Step 3:** do the same for the role subsystem:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <roleManager defaultProvider="YourProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
          <providers>
             <clear />
             <add name="YourProvider" 
                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"                 
                  connectionStringName="ASPNETDB_Connection"
                  applicationName="MyApplication" />
          </providers>
      </roleManager>
```

Comment: Is ASPNETDB created for all applications or separate db is created for every application? Can I do something with already existing ASPNETDB which is created by VS? How can I use the same ASPNETDB on a shared hosting server where I need to create any db with my domain-name prefix?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: it's **one** database for all applications to use. The `ASPNETDB.MDF` file provided by Visual Studio can be attached to SQL Server and used from there on out - no problems to be expected. Not sure about your last question - don't understand the problem/requirement...

Comment: what I meant by second question is, I now created ASPNETDB, and I also have ASPNETDB created by VS.. can I combine data in both into one I created by utility? and about third question, in shared web hosting service they don't provide any dedicated server, all domains need to create their dbs with domainName prefix..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: if you now have two copies of the same database, you need to 1) attach the second one (created by VS) under a different name, and 2) copy over those rows that you still need. There's no magic "merge" functionality out there, I'm afraid